# Getting an ASP.MVC2/VS2010 application to work in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I've recently downloaded beta 2 of VS2010 and started playing with ASP.NET MVC2. Initial development was done with Casini, but now I wanted to run the application from IIS 7.5 (I'm running Windows 7).
I've installed the IIS6 metabase compatiblity and I run VS2010 as administrator so I can use the "Create Virtual Directory" button from the "Web" tab of the project settings.
This created the web application entry in IIS, but it doesn't work.

When I go to the main page (http://localhost/MyMvcApp/) I get a HTTP 403 error. When I go directly to one of the sub-pages (http://localhost/MyMvcApp/Home/) I get an HTTP 404.

So I guess for some reason the URL routing isn't working.
I've already added UrlRouting as a module and a handler to the web.config. In my searches this is offered as a solution for some similair problems. But for me this still doesn't work.

The interesting part of my web.config looke like this:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile>
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
    <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </handlers>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After more checking and trying I noticed in the "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog that "HTTP Errors" and "HTTP Redirection" were missing.
This is strange because as far as I can remember this was installed automatically by the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.
In any case "HTTP Redirection" seemed like a need-to-have feature when working with MVC. So after I installed it everything seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: Ha!  I thought this was the solution I was looking, but sadly it's same symptoms different issue.  +1 and thanks anyway :)

Comment: Weird. I went through the Web Platform Installer and choose defaults (which doesn't include HTTP Redirection) - it worked after that. I'm running Vista/IIS7. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, so thanks :)

Comment: I had the same problems with the RTM versions. Adding HTTP Errors and Redirection did the trick

Comment: Well that pissed me off...finally found the solution LOL thanks Stack Overflow

Answer (score 49):

I've just had this problem, and unfortunately the fix here didn't work for me.

What did work was running this:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

in a command window...works like a dream now!

(So, is ASP.Net not installed into IIS by default when you install VS2010?)

Comment: if IIS was not installed when you installed the framework, you will always need to do this. Not sure if that's your case.

Comment: My problem was slightly different to the one described by the OP, but this solved my problem too. If you're tearing your hair out i would urge you to try this.

Comment: This works; nowadays (especially Windows 8), you may need also to see:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736284 as they don't want that command to be run anymore...

Comment: what does this even do?  is it safe to run on a production environment while other applications are running in IIS?

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!-- rest of config -->
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is such a pain doing this manually. But **definitely doable**! I managed it and summed it up in this step by step guide on [**adding an mvc 2 project to an exisitng web forms solution**](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/05/add-mvc2-project-webforms-application.html) here. Hope this helps... it took me ages to work though all the config settings and there seem to be so few resources on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

What Helped to me is using classic pipeline for AppPool instead of integrated:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you must run aspnet_regiis.exe -ir as administrator, it seems obvious but when you are tired of trying things with no success to solve that, you could pass it.

Just to say a big THANK YOU to all the responses, after many hours trying different things, finally I could get work my MVC 2 app in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I was building an MVC2 application on my laptop Windows 7, using .net beta 2 and 
VS 2010 beta 2. When I installed the entire development environment on Windows Server 2008, including VS, built the solution and ran it, the routing worked fine.

The next step was to create a production server on Windows Server 2008, on which I deployed the .net 4.0 beta but none of the other stuff which came with the VS 2010 beta download.
Under this configuration the routing never worked until I enable HTTP Redirection as indicated by Jeroen.

Hope this helps someone who might be in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to note that I was having the same problem with 403 and 404s but adding the `system.webServer` and all the elements from the `system.web/pages/namespaces` node resolved it for me.