# url containing suffix like *.html does not go through routing?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to register a route with a suffix like *.html using asp.net routing in mvc on iis7?
Or do I have to reconfigure iis to handle this?
My route looks like:

```
"extjs.mvc/{everything}"
```

this url gets routed:

```
/extjs.mvc/blabla
```

and this does not:

```
/extjs.mvc/blabla.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the web platform installer does not activate all features of iis. I followed this answer and that worked:
[link to answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856953/90033)